# new Spark StreamingContext failes with hdfs errors

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, mesosphere, dcos

I'm using dcos installed via Azure ACS and installed hdfs and spark via dcos tool with default options.

Creating a SparkStreamingContext gives:

```
16/07/22 01:51:04 WARN DFSUtil: Namenode for hdfs remains unresolved for ID nn1. Check your hdfs-site.xml file to ensure namenodes are configured properly. 
16/07/22 01:51:04 WARN DFSUtil: Namenode for hdfs remains unresolved for ID nn2. Check your hdfs-site.xml file to ensure namenodes are configured properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
java.net.UnknownHostException: namenode1.hdfs.mesos
```

I expect I have to redeploy the spark package with `dcos package install` with –options= but can't figure out what the `hdfs.config-url` should be. The https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.7/usage/service-guides/spark/install/#hdfs docs seem out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is out of date.  We'll fix that.

DC/OS HDFS now serves its config on http://hdfs.marathon.mesos:[port]/v1/connect